# How to understand closure in a lambda?

Tags: python, lambda, tkinter, closures

I want to make 5 buttons in a loop, and for each buttons bind a commend to print the index. In the following solution it always prints the same index.

My code like this:

```
for i in range(5):
    make_button = Tkinter.Button(frame, text ="make!", 
                                 command= lambda: makeId(i))

def makeId(i):
    print(i)
```

It always prints 5. How can I fix this?

Comment: Wouldn't this always print '4'?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Resolution of variables in lambdas is done when lambda is executed. At this time, for all buttons i=5. To rectify this issue do as follows:

```
 make_button = Tkinter.Button(frame, text ="make!", 
                              command= lambda i=i: makeId(i))
```

This creates i as a local variable in a lambda. This local variable will hold correct value of i from the loop. the local variable can have any name, not necessarily `i`, e.g. `command= lambda a=i: makeId(a))`.