# I want the information to be entered when I press a button with a red background

Tags: python, tkinter

I want the information to be entered when I press a button with a red background.
    / But it doesn't work. / How can I make it enter when the button background is red?

```
color= ['red', 'orange', 'yellow', 'green', 'blue', 'violet', 'purple', 'green yellow', 'snow', 'maroon1']

b0 = tk.Button(root, text = (out0), bg=random.choice(color), command=lambda:code(out0))
if b0 == 'red' :
        pin += str(value)
        e.insert('end', value)
```

Comment: `b0` is a Button.  It will never be equal to the string `"red"`.

Comment: Then how do I change it to enter the b0 button when it is red background?

Comment: Read [how-to-understand-chlosure-in-a-lambda](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28494089)

Comment: "Then how do I change it to enter the b0 button when it is red background?" I can't understand what "enter the button" is supposed to mean.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`if b0 == 'red':` compares the *button* `b0` to the *string* `'red'`. If you think about it, it's clear that a button will never equal a string.

You probably want to get the current background color of the button. Since `bg` is a config option, you can use the [`cget`](https://effbot.org/tkinterbook/widget.htm#Tkinter.Widget.cget-method) method to read its current value:

```py
if b0.cget('bg') == 'red':
```

By the way, if you'd want to *change* the `bg` config value on an already existing widget, you could use the [`config`](https://effbot.org/tkinterbook/widget.htm#Tkinter.Widget.config-method) method: `b0.config(bg='red')`. For more info about configuration in Tkinter, see [this page](https://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-widget-configuration.htm).

Note that for convenience, Tkinter widgets also implement a partial dictionary interface, so you can also use `b0['bg']` to read or write the value.

Comment: As you said, I changed it using Cget and it was only entered if the next color was red.

Comment: All I want is information entered only when the color is red.