# How to communicate between sibling objects in Python, when using Composition, not Inheritance

Tags: python, methods, composition

I have a parent object which is composed of 2 (different) child objects.
The 2 child instances need to communicate. For example, assume child1 needs to send something to child2:

```
import children

class Parent:
    def __init__(self):
        self.child1 = children.Child1(self.q)
        self.child2 = children.Child2(self.q)

parent = Parent()
parent.child1.send("string")
```

Is there a recommended pattern to achieve this?

---

The best I could come up with was to create a Queue between the 2 objects. This works, but it requires the receiving object to run a thread. For example:

**parent.py**:

```
import children
import queue
import time

class Parent:
    def __init__(self):
        
        self.q = queue.Queue()
        self.child1 = children.Child1(self.q)
        self.child2 = children.Child2(self.q)

parent = Parent()
parent.child1.send("string")
time.sleep(1)
```

**children.py**:

```
import threading

class Child1:

    def __init__(self, q):
        self.q = q

    def send(self, item):
        self.q.put(item)

class Child2:

    def __init__(self, q):
        self.q = q
        self.receiver = threading.Thread(target=self.worker, daemon=True).start()

    def worker(self):
        """Process the queue"""
        while True:
            item = self.q.get()
            print(f"{item} received")
```

In practice, the "items" I send in the queue are a function name and an argument list. This is basically the Command pattern as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/683945/6923332). But I don't like the need for receiver threads.

I would prefer if it was possible to allow one object to directly call a method in the other object.
If there was an *inheritance* relationship between them, with a common parent, I could maybe use `super()` for this:

```
class Child1:

    def send(self, function, arguments):
        super().child2.function(arguments)
```

But there is no inheritance in my case: just composition.
Is there a better way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just construct the children with a reference back to the parent:

```py
class Child1:
    def __init__(self, parent):
        self.parent = parent

    def send(self, msg):
        self.parent.child2.print_out(msg)

class Child2:
    def __init__(self, parent):
        self.parent = parent

    def print_out(self, msg):
        print(msg)

class Parent:
    def __init__(self):
        self.child1 = Child1(self)
        self.child2 = Child2(self)

parent = Parent()
parent.child1.send("foo")
```

Comment: Wow, that was fast! Thank you.

Comment: This will be very tightly coupled, no?  A `Parent` needs to know that it has a `Child1` and a `Child2`; a `Child1` needs to know it belongs to a `Parent` that also has a `Child2`; and a `Child2` needs to know it belongs to a `Parent` that also has a `Child1`.  Since one of the major selling features of composition is loose coupling, won't this defeat the purpose of using composition?

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you're looking for is the [Façade Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facade_pattern).

Presumably, `Parent` is more than just a namespace; it knows things and does stuff. Having `Child1` send something to `Child2` seems like it would be a behaviour of `Parent`, the implementation of which is abstracted away, hidden behind the façade.

```py
class Foo:

    def send_msg(self):
        return f'This is a message sent from {self.__class__.__name__}.'


class Bar:

    def receive_msg(self, msg):
        print(self.__class__.__name__, 'has received the following message:'
        print('\t', msg)


class Facade:

    def __init__(self):
        self.foo = Foo()
        self.bar = Bar()

    def foo_the_bar(self):
        self.bar.receive_msg(self.foo.send_msg())
```

```
>>> facade = Facade()
>>> facade.foo_the_bar()
Bar has received the following message:
     This is a message sent from Foo.
```